# AWS Cloud Formations Configuring a webserver to connect to an ELB front ending an app server?

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, autoscaling

I found this great tutorial from Amazon on using [cloud formation to provision](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/example-templates-autoscaling.html) an elb in front of a web server with auto scaling.  What I want to do is extend this to also create a second elb with an app server behind it.  I can figure out that part, but once I do I then want to configure the web server (I guess in httpd.conf to establish the connection from the web server to the app elb.  does anyone have guidance on how to do this?